# Transform a data frame into binary matrix, with the rownames' matrix being the cells info of the original df and the colnames being the df headers

Tags: r, dataframe, matrix, converters

I have a data frame with different columns that are groups and the cells of these columns are the species that belog to the column group. I need to convert this into a binary matrix, in which the columns continuing to be the header (groups) but the rows are going to be the species, then if a species were originially in that column group it will be 1, otherwise will be 0.

```
# Load the dplyr package
library(dplyr)

# Create a list of vectors with different lengths
list_of_vectors <- list(
  Z1 = c("E","F","G"),
  Z2 = c("A", "B", "C", "D"),
  Z3 = c("H","I","J","K","L")
)

# Find the maximum length
max_length <- max(sapply(list_of_vectors, length))

# Pad the vectors with NA to make them the same length
padded_vectors <- lapply(list_of_vectors, function(x) c(x, rep(NA, max_length - length(x))))

# Create the data frame using dplyr
df <- as.data.frame(bind_cols(padded_vectors))
```

**I want to go FROM this:**

```
# data frame
   Z1   Z2    Z3
1   E    A     H
2   F    B     I
3   G    C     J
4   NA   D     K
5   NA   NA    L
```

**to this:**

```
# binary matrix
   Z1   Z2  Z3
E  1    0    0
F  1    0    ...
G  1    0
A  0    1
B  0    1
C  0    1
D  ..   1
H       0    1
I            1
J            ...
K
L
```

Thank you!

Comment: fyi, `data.frame(lapply(list_of_vectors, \`length<-\`, max(lengths(list_of_vectors))))`, introducing both `lengths(list_of_vectors)` instead of `sapply(..)`, and `\`length<-\`` as a way to append `NA` values to a particular length.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```r
out <- +sapply(df, `%in%`, x = sort(unique(na.omit(unlist(df)))))
rownames(out) <- sort(unique(na.omit(unlist(df))))
out
#   Z1 Z2 Z3
# A  0  1  0
# B  0  1  0
# C  0  1  0
# D  0  1  0
# E  1  0  0
# F  1  0  0
# G  1  0  0
# H  0  0  1
# I  0  0  1
# J  0  0  1
# K  0  0  1
# L  0  0  1
```

or as a one-liner:

```r
with(list(r = sort(unique(na.omit(unlist(df))))), 
     `rownames<-`(+sapply(df, `%in%`, x = r), r))
```

Notes:

- I added `na.omit` because I did not assume you wanted to know where `NA`s existed. Over to you if you think it's useful.
- I added `sort` because I thought it made more sense visually, but it's completely optional.
- `unique` is not strictly required but will produce same-named rows without it.

Finally, though: this is an indicator of *presence*, meaning that if we have a letter repeated in a column, we see only `1`:

```r
df$Z2[1] <- "B"
with(list(r = sort(unique(na.omit(unlist(df))))), `rownames<-`(+sapply(df, `%in%`, x = r), r))
#   Z1 Z2 Z3
# B  0  1  0
# C  0  1  0
# D  0  1  0
# E  1  0  0
# F  1  0  0
# G  1  0  0
# H  0  0  1
# I  0  0  1
# J  0  0  1
# K  0  0  1
# L  0  0  1
```

If you need it to be a *count*, then we need

```r
with(list(r = sort(unique(na.omit(unlist(df))))), 
     `rownames<-`(sapply(df, function(col) colSums(outer(col, r, `==`), na.rm = TRUE)), r))
#   Z1 Z2 Z3
# B  0  2  0
# C  0  1  0
# D  0  1  0
# E  1  0  0
# F  1  0  0
# G  1  0  0
# H  0  0  1
# I  0  0  1
# J  0  0  1
# K  0  0  1
# L  0  0  1
```

---

Data

```r
df <- structure(list(Z1 = c("E", "F", "G", NA, NA), Z2 = c("A", "B", "C", "D", NA), Z3 = c("H", "I", "J", "K", "L")), row.names = c(NA, -5L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 1):

Probably you can use `table` like below

```
> table(stack(df))[na.omit(unlist(df)), ]
      ind
values Z1 Z2 Z3
     E  1  0  0
     F  1  0  0
     G  1  0  0
     A  0  1  0
     B  0  1  0
     C  0  1  0
     D  0  1  0
     H  0  0  1
     I  0  0  1
     J  0  0  1
     K  0  0  1
     L  0  0  1
```

where `na.omit(unlist(df))` can be directly used as the row names of the table and reorder the rows.

Comment: thank you! This also worked too. I tried to use `table(stack()...` before, but without sucess. That is nice!